# using LIKE in Sql in PHP web page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the code below to search for the text 'english' anywhere in the field language. I've tried formatting the code from SQL into a web PHP page but it doesn't display any information. When I run the sql version select `language` from `media` where `language` like '%english%' it works.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `language` FROM `media` WHERE `language` LIKE \'%english%\'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[''];
echo ' ' , $row['language'];
echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape the single quotes around your search term.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `language` FROM `media` WHERE `language` LIKE '%english%'");
```

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin and it formatted the php code with the \. thanks its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the `'`'s. It should just work. So try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `language` FROM `media` WHERE `language` LIKE '%english%'");
```